# clap capture all remaining arguments in one field in Derive API?

Tags: rust, clap

I am using clap v3.1.18 with following code.

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about = ABOUT_TEXT, long_about = Some(ABOUT_TEXT))]
struct Args {


    /// The root folder on local filesystem to scan
    #[clap(short, long, default_value_t = utils::get_current_dir())]
    folder: String,

    /// Max number of recursive folders to scan
    #[clap(short, long, default_value_t = 5)]
    depth: u8,

    /// Regular expression to include files. Only files whose name matches the specified regexp will be listed. E.g. to only list *.dll and *.exe files, you can specify `((\\.dll)$)|((\\.exe)$)`
    #[clap(short, long, default_value(".+"))]
    include: String,

    /// Regular expression to include files. Regular expression to exclude files and directories. Files or directories whose name matches this regexp will be skipped
    #[clap(short, long, default_value("(^~)|(^\\.)|((\\.tmp)$)|((\\.log)$)"))]
    exclude: String,

    /// Command line to start child process
    #[clap(multiple_occurrences=true, use_delimiter=false)]
    command: String,
}
let args = Args::parse();
```

The last `command`, I want to get all the remaining part in the command line, including whitespaces.  But current code does not work and it is terminated by the first whitespace.

I think I should set `.setting(AppSettings::TrailingVarArg)`, but don't find a way to do that in Derive API.  Please how can this be done?

---

Thanks @MeetTitan, here is my code finnally works

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about = ABOUT_TEXT, long_about = Some(ABOUT_TEXT), trailing_var_arg=true)]
struct Args {


    /// The root folder on local filesystem to scan
    #[clap(short, long, default_value_t = utils::get_current_dir())]
    folder: String,

    /// Max number of recursive folders to scan
    #[clap(short, long, default_value_t = 5)]
    depth: u8,

    /// Regular expression to include files. Only files whose name matches the specified regexp will be listed. E.g. to only list *.dll and *.exe files, you can specify `((\\.dll)$)|((\\.exe)$)`
    #[clap(short, long, default_value(".+"))]
    include: String,

    /// Regular expression to include files. Regular expression to exclude files and directories. Files or directories whose name matches this regexp will be skipped
    #[clap(short, long, default_value("(^~)|(^\\.)|((\\.tmp)$)|((\\.log)$)"))]
    exclude: String,

    /// Command line to start child process
    #[clap(long, multiple_values=true, allow_hyphen_values=true)]
    run: Vec<String>,
}
```

Comment: Try `command: Vec<String>`?

Comment: If you mark the arg with `last=true` that would also do the trick. See [last()](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.last)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [derive reference](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/v3.1.18/examples/derive_ref/README.md) states:

> Any [`Command` method](https://docs.rs/clap/3.1.18/clap/type.Command.html) can also be used as an attribute, see [Terminology](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/v3.1.18/examples/derive_ref/README.md#terminology) for syntax.

> e.g. `#[clap(arg_required_else_help(true))]` would translate to `cmd.arg_required_else_help(true)`

Using this we can derive `.setting(AppSettings::TrailingVarArg)`, (more accurately, [`App::trailing_var_arg()`](https://docs.rs/clap/3.1.18/clap/struct.App.html#method.trailing_var_arg)) like so:

```
#[clap(... trailing_var_arg=true)]
struct Args { ... }
```

Comment: You may also want `allow_hyphen_values=true` inside the directive, as mentioned in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to a similar problem for a more recent `clap 4.4.8`:

```rust
/// A dummy command that accepts any arguments
#[derive(clap::Args, Clone, Debug)]
struct DummyCommandArgs {
    #[arg(trailing_var_arg = true, allow_hyphen_values = true, hide = true)]
    _args: Vec<String>,
}
```

If you want to actually use the arguments, you probably want to get rid of `hide=true`. This should also work with additional arguments.